# NOT EXISTS clause in SQL

Tags: sql, not-exists

I have been stuck on a query and I am really not able to think how does the execution takes place, any help will be highly appreciated :

The query is devised to find the details of the employee who works on all the projects.

The query is :

```
SELECT E.LNAME, E.FNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT PNUMBER
    FROM PROJECT
    WHERE PNUMBER NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT PNO 
        FROM WORKS_ON
        WHERE ESSN=E.SSN 
    ) 
);
```

DB Structure is :

Table Projects with columns :

> Pname,Pnumber,Plocation and dnum

Table works_on with columns :

> ESSN,PNO and HOURS

Table Employee with columns :

> Fname,minit,Lname,SSN,Bdate,address, sex,salary,superssn and dno

If someone can explain in simple words how this query executes it will be really helpful.

Comment: `WHERE PNUMBER NOT EXISTS`...that's odd. What RDBMS is this?

Comment: What is relation between employee and project table?

Comment: What output is the query throwing ? Error ? Unwanted data ?

Comment: Read on Subqueries with NOT EXISTS from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184297(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 10):

The SQL EXISTS condition is considered "to be met" if the subquery returns at least one row.

Therefore, by implying NOT EXISTS, we want the subquery to return zero rows, so with that knowledge let's look at your query

```
SELECT E.LNAME, E.FNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PNUMBER
FROM PROJECT
WHERE PNUMBER NOT EXISTS (SELECT PNO 
FROM WORKS_ON
WHERE ESSN=E.SSN ) );
```

There are two nested NOT EXISTS statement, and SQL will have to run them in reverse order, because one relies on the other.  The first one which will be queried is this one (the last one):

```
SELECT PNO 
    FROM WORKS_ON
    WHERE ESSN=E.SSN
```

If this returns zero rows (because we've said NOT EXISTS), then it will run the next query, which will be:

```
SELECT PNUMBER
    FROM PROJECT
```

Again, this has to return zero rows, and if it does, then it will run the final query, which is the first one.

```
SELECT E.LNAME, E.FNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E
```

In essence, every "NOT EXIST" subquery has to return zero rows for the preceding query to run, otherwise you will end up with 0 rows (no results).

More information about the EXISTS condition [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php)

Comment: Thanks. I get the logic but am not sure how the output will come fetching the employee record who will work on all projects.   consider the sub query :

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I was intrigued so I spent some time on it and it would be a waste to let the effort be lost.

First of all, I don't know the syntax of the inner `<column name> NOT EXISTS <subquery>` but it seems to be equivalent to `<column name> NOT IN <subquery>`. Just this notion made the query more comprehensive for me because it more clearly links the inner query to the *PROJECT*.
So I started from

```
SELECT E.LNAME, E.FNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT PNUMBER
    FROM PROJECT
    WHERE PNUMBER NOT IN
    (
        SELECT PNO
        FROM WORKS_ON
        WHERE ESSN=E.SSN
    )
);
```

### Breakdown of the steps:

- The inner query simply lists all the project numbers that your employee works on.

  ```
          SELECT PNO
          FROM WORKS_ON
          WHERE ESSN=E.SSN
  ```
- The middle query takes the complement. The result is all the project numbers that your employee does not work on.

  ```
      SELECT PNUMBER
      FROM PROJECT
      WHERE PNUMBER NOT IN
      (
          -- projects that the employee works on
      )
  ```
- If there are projects existing where the employee doesn't work on then he doesn't work on all of them and he should therefor not be included in the results.

  ```
  SELECT E.LNAME, E.FNAME
  FROM EMPLOYEE E
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
      -- projects that the employee does not work on
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [keyszers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2094571/keyszers) is more than sufficient for this question. However I would like to add few more points

The execution of SQL query starts from the inner query. Hence in your Query the one in where clause executes first

> WHERE PNUMBER NOT EXISTS 
>           (
>               SELECT PNO 
>               FROM WORKS_ON
>               WHERE ESSN=E.SSN 
>           )

based on the result of above query the other query below will run.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT PNUMBER
    FROM PROJECT
    WHERE PNUMBER NOT EXISTS (**Resultset**)
```

To summarise my point - You need to debug your query based on the resultsets in the subqueries.